# Which Qt widget (not webkit) that can display html image link (like item list)

Tags: c++, qt

i like to display image from server without downloading it , sure i can use qwebkit.
but i like to be able to display the image in some kind of list . what option do i have ?

Comment: If you want to show it from a server you always have to download it. You probably mean without downloading it manually but automaticly by a QWidget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that `QTextEdit` supports `img` tags, and I use them in lists. However, I don't know if it actually supports full URLs for those images, I just use images from the resource file. You could however give it a try.

Use `setHTML()` to set the HTML source code, `setText()` assumes plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

You -have to- download the image manually and load it into a QPixmap to show it. You can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to download the image, it's pretty solid and works on virtually any platform. And really easy to use.